# Eclipse IDE Layout controls

Tags: android

I'm new to android development and i seem to be catching on pretty fast although i am having some problems while working with the layout, it seems that every time i create a layout and test it on my device nothing seems to be located in the same place as to where i placed it when first loading the application, the funny part about this is it seems to correct itself after hitting a button. i have here just a simple online radio app and as i said everything seems to load in the top of the screen but when pressing the play button all controls relocate to the proper location. could anybody help me with this or tell me as to what im doing wrong ?

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.dirtroadfm.MainActivity" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="199dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dirtroadfm"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/volbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/volbar"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/volbar"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/volbar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="21dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnStop"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnStop"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/volbar"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="31dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If this your complete code, you need to close <relative/> tag

Comment: there is a close on it, it ends with `</RelativeLayout>` sorry it didnt include it in the post, also i just noticed that when the app first loads everything is aligned to the top, when pressing play everything acts as it should and the layout positions itself in the correct place then after the music starts everything aligns itself to the top again. does it have something to do with my xml ?

Comment: Well, you may try to use other containers like LinearLayout. This might help you solve your problem.